# cython compilation error 'is not a type identifier'

Tags: python, gcc, types, cython

I have been trying to pip install a package for a while which is returning the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        return compare >= 0

cdef inline bint cmp(x, y):
    return (x > y) - (x < y)

cdef Strand parse_strand(str strand):
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

wrenlab/genome/types.pyx:35:5: 'Strand' is not a type identifier
```

...

```
#error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
  ^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I was able to get it working on some computers but not others.
Does anyone know where the best place to start would be with this problem?  It appears to be an issue with cython or gcc, but I have installed the proper version which is requested in the source code.

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at the package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wrenlab/0.1.2 and the code does not define `Strand` nor does it import or include code that would. It is weird that it works at all on some computers. Contact the authors of the code to inquire about its status (beta/working/version of Python, etc).